# How to recover Postgres replication slave after fatal error

Tags: postgresql, replication

On 4 Debian 8 Jessie servers, I have PostgreSQL 9.4.3 master + 3 slaves. After substantial data changes on master, slave logs showed this error:

`LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 182/0 on timeline 1
FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 000000010000018200000000 has already been removed`

What steps do i need to restore/rebuild the slaves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set up an `archive_command` and have your WAL segments saved elsewhere, you can just point a `restore_command` in the `recovery.conf` on each of the secondaries at your WAL archive, and they should grab the next needed segment and carry on happily.

If you didn't set up an `archive_command`, you'll need to take a `pg_basebackup` on each of your secondaries, because without that WAL segment, they can never catch up. Since you're on 9.4, I would recommend also setting up a replication slot, which will prevent the primary from recycling a WAL segment that is required for the streaming replicas.

You can find more out about this with the [replication slot](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS) documentation.

Otherwise, you need to have an `archive_command` set that saves the WAL elsewhere to catch up, or you need to adjust `wal_keep_segments` high enough on the primary that it doesn't recycle files under heavy load on your system.

Setting up the `archive_command` in your `postgresql.conf` is covered in the [Continuous Archiving and Point In Time Recovery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html) documentation.

An example of a similar situation to the one you are in, and one potential solution to prevent it, is covered in [Offsite Replication Problems and How to Solve Them](http://evol-monkey.blogspot.com/2014/09/offsite-replication-problems-and-how-to.html).

Hopefully this is enough information for you to get your replicas back to a working state. =)

Comment: could you elaborate how/where to check archive_command? Thanks for an in-depth reply!

Comment: @Yurik I edited and elaborated on my answer per your request. =)